# Searching for a word in multiple file : Process the files with hashmap JAVA

Tags: java, string, file, search, hashmap

I am trying to process the list of files to store the word as :

```
 // <word,<filename, <count, position[]>>> something like this

 private static void processFile(List<File> list) throws IOException {

   int fcount = 0;
    for (File file : list) {
      String fileName = file.getName();
      // System.out.println(fileName);
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(file);
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
      String readLine = "";
      int pos = 0;
      while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>> fList;
        String[] words = readLine.split("\\W");

        for (String newWord : words) {

          String word = newWord.toLowerCase();
          ArrayList<Integer> position = null;
          HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> value = null;
          HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> fnameWithCount = null;

          if (fmap.containsKey(word)) {
            fList = fmap.get(word);

            if(fList.contains(fileName)) {
              fnameWithCount =   getMap(fList,fileName);
            }

            int newCount =1;
            if (fnameWithCount != null) {
              value  = fnameWithCount.get(fileName);
              for (int prevcount : value.keySet()) {
                newCount = prevcount +1;
                value.put(newCount,value.remove(prevcount));              
              }
              value.get(newCount).add(pos);
            }  else {
              position = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // position array
              position.add(pos);

              value = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
              value.put(1, position);

              fnameWithCount = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>();
              fnameWithCount.put(fileName, value);

              fList.add(fnameWithCount);
              fmap.put(word, fList);
            }


          } else {
            position = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // position array
            position.add(pos);

            value = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
            value.put(1, position);

            fnameWithCount = new HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>();
            fnameWithCount.put(fileName, value);

            fList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>>();          
            fList.add(fnameWithCount);

            fmap.put(word, fList);

          }

          pos++;
        }
      }
      fcount++;
    }

  }

  private static HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>> getMap(
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>> fList,
      String fileName) {


    for (int i =0 ;i <fList.size();i++) {
     if( fList.get(i).containsKey(fileName)) {
        return fList.get(i);

      }
    }

    return null;
  }

  private static HashMap<String, Integer> hashMapSearch(
      String stringToLookFor) throws IOException {


    if (fmap.containsKey(stringToLookFor.toLowerCase())) {
     System.out.println(fmap.get(stringToLookFor.toLowerCase()).toString());
    }

        return null;

  }
```

My output Looks like :

```
{File1={1=[0]}}, {File1={1=[37]}}, {File1={1=[72]}}, {File1={1=[93]}}, {File1={1=[106]}}, {File1={1=[111]}}, {File1={1=[120]}}, {File1={1=[123]}}, {File1={1=[132]}}, {File1={1=[143]}}, {File1={1=[170]}}, {File1={1=[178]}}, {File1={1=[187]}}, {File1={1=[191]}}, {File1={1=[203]}}, {File1={1=[212]}}, {File1={1=[219]}}, {File1={1=[228]}}, {File1={1=[232]}}, {File1={1=[249]}}, {File1={1=[253]}}, {File1={1=[260]}}, {File1={1=[272]}}, {File1={1=[279]}}, {File1={1=[284]}}, {File1={1=[305]}}, {File1={1=[333]}}, {File1={1=[337]}}, {File1={1=[340]}}, {File1={1=[351]}}, {File1={1=[367]}}, {File1={1=[377]}}, {File1={1=[391]}}, {File1={1=[403]}}, {File1={1=[420]}}, {File1={1=[427]}}, {File1={1=[437]}}, {File1={1=[445]}}, {File1={1=[474]}}, {File1={1=[479]}}, {File1={1=[485]}}, {File1={1=[495]}}, {File1={1=[519]}}, {File1={1=[522]}}, {File1={1=[526]}}, {File1={1=[529]}}, {File1={1=[555]}}, {File1={1=[571]}}, {File1={1=[582]}}, {File1={1=[604]}}, {File1={1=[607]}}, {File1={1=[611]}}, {File1={1=[618]}}, {File1={1=[623]}}, {File1={1=[628]}}, {File1={1=[640]}}, {File1={1=[644]}}, {File1={1=[663]}}, {File1={1=[683]}}, {File1={1=[689]}}, {File1={1=[699]}}, {File1={1=[708]}}, {File1={1=[715]}}, {File1={1=[725]}}, {File2={1=[0]}}, {File2={1=[5]}}, {File2={1=[100]}}, {File2={1=[140]}}, {File2={1=[145]}}, {File2={1=[153]}}, {File2={1=[171]}}, {File2={1=[184]}}, {File2={1=[207]}}, {File2={1=[210]}}, {File2={1=[214]}}, {File2={1=[219]}}, {File2={1=[223]}}, {File2={1=[234]}}, {File2={1=[244]}}, {File2={1=[247]}}, {File2={1=[259]}}, {File2={1=[264]}}, {File2={1=[270]}}, {File2={1=[273]}}, {File2={1=[278]}}, {File2={1=[326]}}, {File2={1=[331]}}, {File2={1=[340]}}, {File2={1=[355]}}, {File2={1=[367]}}, {File2={1=[371]}}, {File2={1=[375]}}, {File2={1=[378]}}, {File3={1=[47]}}, {File3={1=[68]}}, {File3={1=[73]}}, {File3={1=[102]}}, {File3={1=[121]}}, {File3={1=[161]}}]
```

But its supposed to be :

```
 [{File1={64=[array of positions]}}, {File2={29=[array of positions]}},  {File3={6=[array of positions]}}]
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here ? Also is it good to use the map for storing  like this :     `// <word,<filename, <count, position[]>>> something like this`
or Can I use like this :

```
class SearchWord {
        String word;
        HashMap<String, Integer> fileNameWithCount; // <fileName, count>
         HashMap<String, List<Integer>> positionList;  //<fileName, pos[]>
        }
```

Can someone suggest which is good or what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: You don't need a count if you have a list of positions, because it is trivial to get the size of a list. But you will have to then format the output. Otherwise, generally maps are bad data structure because they don't show any semantics but you seem to be doing an assignment so it is probably ok.

Comment: @MiserableVariable I am trying to figure out which is best way to store the index to make search easier.

Comment: The "supposed to be" output is for a single word, right? 
`class Matches { String fileName; List<Integer> positions}; class Word { String word; List<Matches> matches; }; List<Word>;` seems most appropriate, with proper `toString()` so you don't have to format while printing.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you change the 'if' condition :

```
for (int i = 0; i < fList.size(); i++) {
  if (fList.get(i).containsKey(fileName)) {
     fnameWithCount =   getMap(fList,fileName);
  }
}
```

Previously, you were trying to use the 'contains' method on `ArrayList<HashMap<String, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>>>();`
to see if the filename is already in the list. But that check was evaluating to
false every time.

Comment: but then only first file has changed to expected. Is there any way I can get map inside the ArrayList based on the map's key ? with out using for loop ? it works fine with loop through the fList size

Comment: @Sarah, My bad, I have edited my answer. yes you can get the map based on the key which is the filename.  I don't see it possible without using a loop as you have got to check if the filename is present anywhere inside the list and so we need a loop